# Confused about deploying to ios 5.0, which xcode to use

Tags: xcode, ios5, deployment, ios6

I want my app to run on iOS 5.0 and all newer versions. Should I do all my development work in Xcode 4.2.1, or use the Xcode 4.5 beta? If I implement maps, then will devices running ios 5.0 show google maps while future devices running ios 6.0 show apple maps?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use Xcode 4.4.1 it's the latest non-beta version.

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Answer (score 3):

XCode 4.5 beta is for testing and report bugs to apple, test iOS 6, etc. You cannot submit an app with it.